# too many re-renders. react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop even when the functions are fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Form = (props) => {
  const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false);

  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    location: ""
  });

  
  const InputHandle = async (event) => {
    setInputData({ ...inputData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
return (
    <div>
      <form id="form" method="GET">
        <div className="inputs">
          <label for="firstname"> First Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstname"
            name="firstname"
            onChange={InputHandle}
          ></input>
        </div>
<div className="inputs">
          <label for="location">User accessing application from</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="location"
            name="location"
            onChange={InputHandle}
          ></input>
          <Link to="/dashboard">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn"
              onClick={() => {
                props.getData(inputData);
              }}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

App.js

```
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Form from "./components/Form";

import "./App.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const getData = (inputData) => {
    setData(inputData);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Form getdata={getData()} />}></Route>
          <Route
            exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard data={data} />}
          ></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am getting this error "too many re-renders. react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."
I don't know what exactly I am doing wrong here, could anyone please help.
To help you understand: I have created a form where I want to take the input(name and location) from the user and show that input on a different page. I tried to integrate googleMaps API to show the location as per the input and m entire code crashed, otherwise it was working fine earlier, also if anyone could help me with the map here too? I have been banging my head trying to do it. I can display the map on a different page but I want to display the location on the map when the user writes any location in the input field of the form, hope I make sense.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you sure this is the component with the error?

Comment: Few things... Input is not pair tag, there is no need for that handle to be async, you left out end of the code, this component seems fine otherwise.

Comment: @MalwareMoon Do you mean this one? onClick={() => {
                props.getData(inputData);
              }}  I tried adding it withing async function but it gave me errors

Comment: @acdcjunior Ok, I'll look into it then, could you also help me with my next question? Google maps one??

Comment: @MalwareMoon In my app.js (code is mentioned above) route exact path="/" element={<Form getdata={getData()} />}></Route> in this line of code when I remove the brackets after getdata. I don't see that error but then my form doesn't work, it doesn't show the input data on the page because it says getData is not a function.....what do I do now???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this line is going to call getData() every time it's rendered, and then pass `undefined` as the prop value:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Form getdata={getData()} />}></Route>
```

`getData` calls a state setter, which seems likely to cause an infinite loop.

I believe it should instead use:

```
getdata={getData}
```

Comment: when I remove the brackets after getdata. I don't see that error but then my form doesn't work, it doesn't show the input data on the page because it says getData is not a function.....what do I do now???

Answer (score 2):

It's 2 part problem. First problem was answered by @JLRishe. The second problem is that your form prop is called `getdata` instead of `getData` and thus the function does not exists and form is not functioning.

This is your final code

```js
<Route exact path="/" element={<Form getData={getData} />}></Route>
```

The reason to why this you were stuck in loop is, that giving form props as `getData={getData()}` you are sending a result of that function as a prop and not the function. And that function calculates on every render, which causes another render.

Stripped down Codepen here

[image: Edit aged-bird-fwmv1y]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!!! Could you also help me with the second question? I want to integrate a google map Api so that if the user write the location in the input field it highlight that particular area. I have been following tutorials which show how to do this but I am just able to integrate that map in a separate webpage but I want to display it only when this form is filled and submitted? can you prefer any document or any video if this solution will take a lot of your time?

Comment: @ashrth If you need help with something else, just make another question.

Comment: can you please answer this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/74714225/19336351